# How to user after_create callback method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I want to call `update_balance(transaction)` along with the `transaction` parameter after create action in the controller. The `update_balance(transaction)' is in model. The code is as follows:
Transactions Controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
  end

def create
  @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
  @transaction.account = current_account
  redirect_to root_path
end

private

def transaction_params
  params.require(:transaction).permit(:amount, :transaction_type)
end
end
```

And the code in model is as follows:

Transaction Model.rb

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :update_balance
  def update_balance(transaction)
     @transaction = transaction
     if transaction.transaction_type == 'debit'
          deposit_balance
     else
          credit_balance
      end
   end

  def deposit_balance
    balance = @transaction.account.current_balance-= @transaction.amount
    if balance.positive?
      save_transaction
    end
  end

def credit_balance
  @transaction.account.current_balance += @transaction.amount
  save_transaction
end

private

  def save_transaction
    @transaction.account.save
    @transaction.save
  end
end
```

This code is throwing error as: `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`> So added the `transaction` parameter in the after-create action too. But it is not working. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your controller:

```
def create
  @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
  @transaction.account = current_account
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

You're initializing a new `Transaction` object but it's never saved! You need to call `@transaction.save` for it to be created, and then the callback will fire as expected.

You could otherwise use `Transaction.create` in place of `Transaction.new` if that suits your need, but using `::new` then `save` is totally fine too.

---

Second problem: you're putting `after_create :update_balance` inside the `Account` model, which mean it will fire when an Account is created, not a Transaction!

Try moving it to the correct model.

Comment: I added `@transaction.save` in create action. The transaction is getting saved in the transaction table. But it is not doing any changes in the account.current_balance in account's table, like crediting or debiting the amount from current_balance. Why so??

Comment: @Neha I updated my answer. Put `after_create` in the correct model and it should work

Comment: I moved all the methods, from account model to transaction model. However , I also want to pass the parameter `transaction` from create action in the :update_transaction method. How to do that? I have updated the code as above and getting the following error.

Comment: @Neha you don't need the `transaction` parameter as the method call is the transaction's own method, i.e. `self` is the transaction that has just been created

Comment: But then how do implement the rest of the code given here? Like to check transaction_type, calling account object associated with `transaction` and the debit, credit methods?

Comment: @Neha If a method is defined on `Transaction`, then you can use it directly, e.g. if you can do `transaction.account` then you can do `self.account` or `account` alone directly.

Comment: Thanks @Geoffroy,  current_balnce is now getting updated.